# ReactJS/Enzyme: How to test a submit function, which calls a graphQL mutation via prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I'm trying to write a unit test (enzyme/jest) for this function:

```
_onSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  const { username, password } = this.state

  this.props.createUserMutation({
    variables: { username, password }
  }).then(response => {
    const token = response.data.createUser.token
    if (token) {
        this.setState({ token })
    }
  }).catch(error => {
    console.warn(error)
  })
}
```

But I don't know how to handle `this.props.createUserMutation()` for proper testing.

Of course my current attempt throws a `TypeError: _this.props.createUserMutation is not a function` error

**Unit test**

```
it('_onSubmit() should submit form and reset state object', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<CreateAccount />)
  wrapper.setState({ username: 'Username', password: 'Password' })
  wrapper.find(Form).simulate('submit', {
    preventDefault: () => {}
  })
  const state = wrapper.instance().state
  expect(state).toEqual({ token: 'test' })
})
```

---

**Updated unit test**

```
it('_onSubmit() should submit data and get result dataset', () => {
    const createUserMutation = () => {
      return Promise.resolve({
        data: {
          createUser: { token: 'token' }
        }
      })
    }
    const wrapper = shallow(<CreateAccount createUserMutation={createUserMutation} />)
    wrapper.find(Form).simulate('submit', {
      preventDefault: () => {}
    })
    const state = wrapper.instance().state
    expect(state).toEqual({ token: 'token' })
  })
```

`console.log(state)` doesn't give me a `token`.

Comment: `createUserMutation` is just a function that you pass manually down as props right? So why can't you just pass down `createUserMutation` in your `<CreateAccount />`? Not enough code shown to get the full picture.

Comment: @MartinDawson I've updated the post with the component. Please have a look at it. There is not much code, but I don't know how to test that. Hope you can help.

Comment: Where does `createUserMutation` come from when running your code in a browser? Does `withData` or `withApollo` inject this or do you manually pass it down? If the HOC's do inject it, then show these HOC code too.

Comment: @MartinDawson I've added the links to initApollo.js and withData.js, which I'm using. With that I do get the data from the apollo server using a graphQL schema...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `createUserMutation` is injected to props by the `compose` function.

So, what you can do is import the non-default component in your test instead of the 'connected' one.

```
import {CreateAccount} from './CreateAcount';
```

Then, you can pass `createUserMutation` as props directly to the component when mounting it.

```
it('_onSubmit() should submit form and reset state object', () => {
  const createUserMutation = () => {
      return Promise.resolve({
           username: '',
           password: ''
         });
  };
  const wrapper = shallow(<CreateAccount createUserMutation={createUserMutation} />)
   ...
});
```

Given that `createUserMutation` seems to be a function that returns a promise, you can assign it `Promise.resolve()` in order to execute the `then` function which changes the state. Which is basically what you are testing.

Moreover, you're not able to test the `token` change in the state because the verification in the test is being run before the state changing in the method `_onSubmit`. (You can check this by putting `console` statements in both places and see which executes first).

What you need to do is return the promise in your `_onSubmit` method.

```
_onSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  const { username, password } = this.state

  return this.props.createUserMutation({   // returning the promise
    variables: { username, password }
  }).then(response => {
    const token = response.data.createUser.token
    if (token) {
        this.setState({ token })
    }
  }).catch(error => {
    console.warn(error)
  })
}
```

Then, in your unit test you need to simulate the submit event by calling the function directly from `props` in order to put your verifications inside a `then` function. By doing this, you would run your `expect` statement after the state has been changed.

```
it('_onSubmit() should submit data and get result dataset', () => {
    const createUserMutation = () => {
      return Promise.resolve({
        data: {
          createUser: { token: 'token' }
        }
      })
    }
    const wrapper = shallow(<CreateAccount createUserMutation={createUserMutation} />)
    wrapper.find(Form).props().onSubmit({
      preventDefault: () => {}
    }).then(() =< {
       const state = wrapper.instance().state
       expect(state).toEqual({ token: 'token' })
    })
  })
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you use `Promise.resolve()`? So with this I'm mocking the `createUserMutation` and I have to test this function by its own? Or do I misunderstand that?

Comment: Basically, you need the `then` function to be executed in order to test the state change. So, you need a promise that 'resolves' in order for `this.setState()` to be executed.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that. But with that I still get the error `TypeError: _this.props.createUserMutation is not a function`

Comment: If I would use `const createUserMutation = jest.fn()` I'll get the expected error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`. But why do I get ther `is not a function` error, if I use the `Promise.resolve()`?

Comment: Thank you very much for your great help. One last thing for this function test: Please have a look at the first code block of the post. I get a token, which I save as a state value. Is it possible to test this? I set the token as a parameter `return Promise.resolve({ data: { createUser: { token: 'test' } } })`, but `wrapper.instance().state` won't get it.

Comment: That code seems okay. I don't know why `wrapper.instance().state` doesn't get it. Try to put a `debugger;` or `console.log(token)` sentence before `if(token)` to see its value.

Comment: I see you're calling `wrapper.setState` in your test before simulating the submit. Maybe the state is not exactly equal to `{ token: 'test' }`?